# Is this well-defined by the C99 standard?

Tags: c

I've made the linker happy by defining `main` even though there's no `main` function in my program. Is this valid by the C99 standard?

```
void foo()
{
    __asm__ (".globl main\n\n"
        "main:\n"
        "\txorl %eax, %eax\n"
        "\tret");
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b5ecb24d53357d4)

Comment: See how your inline-assembly construct is prefixed with double-underscores (`__`)? That means it is not a standard C language or library feature, therefore your program is not a "valid" C99 program.

Comment: More generalized: does the standard care how `main` is provided in a hosted environment? If there is no `main` function, and somehow I provide a `main` symbol, is it still a well-defined program?

Comment: @Dai: Correct conclusion, but incorrect reasoning. There are identifiers starting with double underscores that are defined by the C99 standard (and by the current C11 standard as well). Examples include `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, and `__STDC_VERSION__`. `__asm__` just doesn't happen to be one of them.

Comment: You can write `main`, or any other function in your program, in any language. The C standard only governs parts written in C. Anything else is just outside of its scope.

Comment: Read yourself: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html

Answer (score 4):

No, the C standard does not define the behaviour of any inline assembly.

Answer (score 3):

An implementation may provide `__asm__` keyword, but only as an *extension*. In particular, C99 standard lists `asm` block within informative (non-normative) section J.5.10 *The asm keyword*:

> The `asm` keyword may be used to insert assembly language directly into
>   the translator output (6.8). The most common implementation is via a
>   statement of the form:
>
> `asm ( character-string-literal );`

To be most precise, you program is not *strictly* conforming. From §4/p5 *Conformance* (emphasis mine):

> A *strictly conforming program* **shall use only those features** of the
>   language and library specified in this International Standard.<sup>2)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

There is no `__asm__` keyword in C so the simple fact of using a keyword not defined in C means your program is not strictly conforming.